# jQuery slideToggle and cookies with many boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I'd like to make many boxes without identifier and onClick close them like:

```
<div class="box">
    <header>I'm the box header<ins></ins></header>
    <h1>Title here</h1>
    <p>I'm a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

With this script

```
$(".box header").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll().slideToggle();
});
```

In the view of task the method of hiding is not so important. The `<box><header></header><content>text</content></box>` and like `$this.next().slideToggle()` is also good for me.

The question is that, how can i add a cookie for the toggled elements, to stay them close on the page refresh.
Like the `$(".tabs:not(.forget)").tabs({cookie: {expires: 1}, collapsible: true});`.

Is it possible without making in ID, and check all the IDs in the cookies?
I'm looking for a better solution for it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does the number and position of the boxes ever change? if they are always the same, you can get the position of the box  `$(this).parent().children().index(this)` and never show boxes with the matching numbers. If they do move around, if the data is coming from a database, you can use ajax to save the id of the article or comment or whatever it is that you are displaying, and exclude that from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I did it -.-

In the case of

```
<div class="box">
    <header>Box Header <ins></ins></header>
    <figure>
        <h1>Header 1</h1>
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <p>Paragraph.</p>
    </figure>
</div>
```

With the JS:

```
$("body .box figure").each(function(i){
    var o = $.cookie('boxopened'+i);
    if (!o) 
    {
        $(this).show();
    }
    else 
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
$("body .box header").click(function(){
    var i = $(this).next().index("body .box figure");
    var o = $.cookie('boxopened'+i);
    if (!o)
    {
        $.cookie('boxopened'+i, 'true'); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        $.cookie('boxopened'+i, ''); 
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Works. Any suggestions for this? How can i make this better?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".box header").click(function(){
    $(.box).slideToggle();
    // Set the cookie here
    var boxState = ($(.box).css('display')=='block')? 1: 0;
    $.cookie("boxState", state);
});
```

You can use [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) to set the cookie.

Comment: Thanks, but i can set the cookie, I just can't identify my box :@

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer:**

I really don't think you can solve this challenge without assigning unique IDs to each of your boxes. From a theoretical standpoint (I'll go out on a limb and say also a practical standpoint), what you're trying to accomplish fits perfectly with the concept of assigning unique IDs. You want to take individual, unique action on individual, unique elements. Trying to accomplish that without having individual, unique IDs is fighting against the fundamental theory itself.

That said, I do appreciate that generating unique IDs on the server side is probably a hassle you'd rather do without. But I think the best answer to your question is to do exactly what you were hoping not to have to do... :-)

Old Answer:

If the boxes will always have the same order in the DOM, you could append the index number of the box to a string, which is then stored in your cookie. Like "2,3,10,13" then on page load, you read the cookie, cookieVal.split(",") then for loop through the values and use the jQuery :eq() selector (http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to do something like

```
$(".box:eq(" + i + ")").hide();
```

Comment: eq() is not good because in case `<boxcontainer><box><box><box></boxcontainer><boxcontainer><box><box><box></boxcontainer>` will not work.

Comment: Bummer. If your tag values aren't very long, what about storing the tags themselves in a cookie string like "cookies,milk,pie,asparagus" and then on page load $('.box').each through them and compare the $(this).text() value to the cookie items.

Comment: Hm. `$("body .box").each(function(i){console.log(i)}` do it fine, so i can identify them by their index on body.

Comment: Good idea, the index values in the .each() should remain consistent, and that would handle the nesting problem. Again, assuming none of the boxes are ever moved out of their order, and no new boxes are ever appended.

Comment: But i still don't have any ideas for dynamic content. Like if I append a box in the middle of the other boxes :D I can handle them, but because the index-sliding the boxes will be messed. :( `OPEN-CLOSE-OPEN` will be `OPEN-CLOSE(justinserted)-OPEN-OPEN`. And in re-arrange the boxes with sortables or droppables it's also messes up everything. :(

Comment: I updated my answer... Nesting boxes, potential changes in order - I just don't think it's possible to do. In fact, I think it'll save you time in the long run to go ahead and assign unique IDs to all your boxes.

Comment: Aw :( But in the tabs() feature in the jQuery does the same what i need didn't it? I mean you can re-arrange the tabs container in the DOM and they will show you the good match.

Comment: If I recall, you're right that the jQuery tabs don't have unique IDs, but the associated content panels do have to have unique IDs. I suspect the cookie is storing the value of the content panel ID, and on page load selects the appropriate tab by looking for $('[href=#contentPanelId]') and setting that tab to be active. So, I'm pretty sure that jQuery tabs do depend on the setting of unique IDs. You can test it removing all the unique IDs in the tabs demos and see if it stil works, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to reference the boxes in a cookie. It could be an ID, class, or if the number of boxes is fixed, and the order doesn't change, it could be a number. I would use an ID (or some other unique attribute) to be safe, because let's say for whatever reason the order of the boxes changes, then the numeric order in the cookie wouldn't match up.

```
var closedBoxesCookie=document.cookie;
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(closedBoxesCookie.split(',')).each(function() {
        $('#' + this).hide();
    });
});
```